# How to efficiently distribute inbound netty.io ByteBuf messages to a ChannelGroup?

Tags: java, netty, bytebuffer

I created a netty.io BootStrap that receives streaming data from a legacy server. The server sends the data using the ISO-8859-1 charset. There is also an internal "protocol" in place that uses different separator bytes:

```
private static final byte GS = 29;  // FS ASCII char 1D (group separator)
private static final byte RS = 30;  // FS ASCII char 1E (record separator)
private static final byte US = 31;  // FS ASCII char 1F (unit separator)

private static final ByteProcessor GROUP_SEPARATOR_LOCATOR = value -> value != GS;
private static final ByteProcessor RECORD_SEPARATOR_LOCATOR = value -> value != RS;
private static final ByteProcessor UNIT_SEPARATOR_LOCATOR = value -> value != US;
```

These ByteProcessor instances are used to split the messages. Every message is finally translated into its corresponding object representation, whereas the keyValueMapping contains the main content from the origin message:

```
public class Update {
    private final String id;    
    private final UpdateType updateType;
    private final Map<String, byte[]> keyValueMapping;
    // SOME OTHER STUFF
}
```

Subsequently all updates are forwarded to all connected web-socket clients which are handled by a separate ServerBootStrap:

```
public void distribute(ChannelGroup recipients, Object msg) {
    Update updateMsg = (Update) msg;
    recipients.writeAndFlush(updateMsg);
}
```

When I activated Java Flight Recording and performed some load tests, I realised that the main allocation hotspots is the method that translates the values from the initial inbound message into am ISO-8859-1 byte array:

```
private byte[] translateValue(ByteBuf in) {
    byte [] result;

    if (!in.hasArray()) {
        result = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
        in.getBytes(in.readerIndex(), result);
    } else {
        result = in.array();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Initially I did not translate the ByteBufs and stored them directly in the Update's keyValueMapping map. Since the ByteBuf object maintains some internal indices (reader, writer, marker etc.) which are not guarded - by design, I was afraid to simply wrap and forward these ByteBufs to different channels (see recipients channelGroup above) and decided to go with this byte[] representation instead.

Inspecting the Java Flight Recording results, **I wonder if there is any recommendation how to distribute unchanged inbound data to a group of different channels without bordering the GC too much?** Learning from the results, direct buffers are used for the given channel, as a lot of new byte arrays are created.

To give more context, I also add the code that performs the remaining message translation:

```
while (in.readableBytes() > 0) {
    ByteBuf keyAsByteBuf = nextToken(in, UNIT_SEPARATOR_LOCATOR);
    String key = translateKey(keyAsByteBuf);

    if (key != null) {
        ByteBuf valueAsByteBuf = nextToken(in, RECORD_SEPARATOR_LOCATOR);
        byte[] value = translateValue(valueAsByteBuf);

        if (value.length > 0) {
            mapping.put(key, value); 
        }
    }
}

private ByteBuf nextToken(ByteBuf in, ByteProcessor locator) {
    int separatorIdx = in.forEachByte(in.readerIndex(), in.readableBytes(), locator);

    if (separatorIdx >= 0) {
        ByteBuf token = in.readSlice(separatorIdx - in.readerIndex());
        in.skipBytes(1);
        return token;
    }
    return in.readSlice(in.readableBytes());
}

private String translateKey(ByteBuf in) {
    return keyTranslator.translate(in);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... Actually, your question is not that simple. I'll try to answer briefly.

You don't need to translate `ByteBuf` to `byte[]` if you don't need that in your app. So I assume you have next structure:

```
public class Update {
    private final String id;    
    private final UpdateType updateType;
    private final Map<String, ByteBuf> keyValueMapping;
}
```

The problem here is that you partially parse `ByteBuf`. So you have java object + `ByteBuf`'s within this java object.

That's totally fine and you can operate with those `ByteBuf's` further. Your class `Update` should implement `ReferenceCounted` interface. So when you do `recipients.writeAndFlush(updateMsg)` (assuming recipients are `DefaultChannelGroup`) netty `DefaultChannelGroup` will handle references to those buffers.

So what happens:

After `recipients.writeAndFlush(updateMsg)`, `DefaultChannelGroup` in loop sends your `updateMsg` to every channel in the list with `channel.writeAndFlush(safeDuplicate(message))`. `safeDuplicate` is special method that handles references to netty `ByteBuf`, so you can send the same buffer to multiple receivers (it actually copies buffers with `retainedDuplicate()`). However, your object is not `ByteBuf`, but java object. Here is code of that method:

```
private static Object safeDuplicate(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof ByteBuf) {
        return ((ByteBuf) message).retainedDuplicate();
    } else if (message instanceof ByteBufHolder) {
        return ((ByteBufHolder) message).retainedDuplicate();
    } else {
        return ReferenceCountUtil.retain(message);
    }
}
```

So, in order to correctly handle references of `ByteBuf` you need to implement `ReferenceCounted` for `ReferenceCountUtil.retain(message)`. Something like that:

```
public class Update implements ReferenceCounted {
    @Override
    public final Update retain() {
        return new Update(id, updateType, makeRetainedBuffers());
    }  

    private Map makeRetainedBuffers() {
       Map newMap = new HashMap();
       for (Entry entry : keyValueMapping) {
           newMap.put(entry.key, entry.value.duplicate().retain())
       }
       return newMap;
    }
}
```

This is just a pseudo code. But you should get the idea. You also have to implement `release()` method within `Update` class and make sure it always releases buffers it holds. And release all buffers inside. I assume you already have the encoder in your pipeline for that `Update` class that will call `release()`.

Another option would be to implement own `DefaultChannelGroup`. In that case you don't have to rely on `safeDuplicate` method. And thus you don't need to implement `ReferenceCounted`, however you'll still need to handle retain, release manually inside that class.

Comment: wow, thanks for this detailed answer! As I understand though, this would imply that I need to create a new instance of the  Update and the non-immutable objects (akka ByteBufs) inside? Whereas with the approach to transform to a byte array, I'd simply have one copy of the Update?

Comment: @u6f6o your problem is not in allocations, but in transformations, right? Also, instance of Update is cheap, it has only 3 fields, so it's fine. ByteBuffers uses `duplicate().retain()`. So, actually, here you create only the wrapper (with int fields like `writerIndex`, `readerIndex`) around underlying actual data. And this is also cheap. Anyway, this could be avoided with custom `DefaultChannelGroup`. Here is how I send same `ByteBuf` to multiple channels - https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server/blob/master/server/core/src/main/java/cc/blynk/server/core/model/auth/Session.java#L204.

Comment: to give a little bit more background: I am receiving financial instrument tick data in my service. Especially when markets open, I receive a crap ton of ticks/updates, thus I also have to take care of GC pressure and that is the reason why that question arose. I am in the lucky situation that I do not have to modify the data itself at all and was wondering, if netty offers any nice mechanics to share non-changable data among different channels without copying data(structures) too much. This is the reason why I thought about converting to byte arrays and simply share them although its ugly.

Comment: Netty allows you to share the same ByteBuf, but you have to manage references count by yourself. Please see my link above for example. P. S. I have the similar situation with the load. I'm handling thousands of requests per seconds.

Comment: I see, you reset the reader index every time after you passed the message to a channel. Thanks for the sources, I overlooked that initially.

Comment: Correct. Also have in mind that in my case both: sender and receiver are handled in same EventLoop. That means no concurrency issue, otherwise, you have to wrap ByteBuf as DefaultChannelGroup does.

Comment: I see, that was one of the questions left on my mind, how this would work with channels from different EventLoops. [As it looks like](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.24.Final/io/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroup.java#187), the DefaultChannelGroup simply creates a duplicate of every ByteBuf in case of several EventLoops. I wonder if it could make sense to write a ByteBuf wrapper that maintains a ThreadLocal for the indices.